# update the Document with uid in Firebas

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The attached image is my firebase db and In the elevated button.

[image]

I wrote code to update the noofdays field but it's not getting updated in firebase nor message/error in the console. I'm trying to learn Firebase and please help me solve the error.

noofdays - is Controller

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    var collection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tripdetails');

    collection.doc(user!.uid).update({'noofdays': _nodays});
  },
  child: const Text("Update"),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Update method is a asynchronous operations let your program complete work while waiting for another operation to finish.
To listen this changes use then to know when is completed and onError to know when has error occurs.

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
              var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tripdetails');
              collection
              .doc(user!.uid).update({'noofdays':_nodays}) 
              .then((value) => print("DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!"),
                    onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"))                    
              },
              child: const Text("Update"),
            ),
```

To learn more read the documentation on asynchronous programming in  https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await